# How to call pl-sql function that takes table of numbers as input with 1 number?

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

I have a function that takes table of Numbers as an input:

```
function foo(ids in custom_array)...
```

where `custom_array` is a table of Numbers.

How do I call this function from SQL query if I need to pass only 1 parameter?

I supposed that this should look like this

```
select * from table(foo(123))
```

but my guess was wrong.

**edit:**
function's declaration looks like this:

```
create or replace function foo(id in custom_array) return
tableof2numbers AS
    mytable tableof2numbers;
    BEGIN
      SELECT cast(
          MULTISET (

/*there goes some super secret business logic*/
/*let's say that here we just do smth like this: */

select 123, 123 from dual

/*because this is not so important for this question*/
          )
          AS tableof2numbers)
      INTO
        mytable
      FROM dual;
      RETURN mytable;
```

where `tableof2numbers` is another custom type which declaration is pretty similar to `custom_array`, but with 2 numbers.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I get this error:
ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'foo'

Comment: PLease show the complete definition of custom_array type and foo.

Comment: What does `foo` return?  Your example call seems to imply that it returns a collection.  It's certainly possible that you have a function that takes a collection as input and returns a collection as output but it is also possible that you're using the wrong syntax to call it.  The parameter should probably be `foo(custom_array(123))` but there isn't enough information to know the full `select` statement.

Comment: @JustinCave I Take back my comment "No, that syntax IS correct" - I mistook `foo` for the name of the table of numbers type.

Comment: select * from table(sys.odcinumberlist(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)) where column_value < 5  will give you 1 2 3 4

Comment: this is how i define "custom_array" type:
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "custom_array" as table of number(20)

Comment: You need to post the code for `function foo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My example:

**1) TYPE**

```
create or replace TYPE "TABLE_OF_NUMBER"    
AS TABLE OF NUMBER
```

**2) FUNCTION**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(
    par IN table_of_number)
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN par(1);
END;
```

**3) SELECT**

```
SELECT foo(table_of_number(123)) FROM dual
```

---

If your function returns table, it will be something like

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE (foo(custom_array(123)))
```

Hope it will help.